# How to return an object from array using key as a string within Observable or lodash?

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash, observable

For a given sample how would I get an individual object (show) from Shows based in the id being a string?

I'm mapping the return to an RXJS Observable so using something from RXJS or lodash would be very helpful.

```
//JSON RETURNED within Observable
    {
  "shows": [
    {
      "id": "1-abc",
      "modified": "2017-08-13 15:54:47",
      "name": "Main Show"
    },
    {
      "id": "2-cde",
      "modified": "2017-08-14 15:54:47",
      "name": "Show Number 2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

From above how to get just the show with id = '2-cde'??

Comment: `let match = data.shows.find(x => x.id === "2-cde");` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: If that's an observable stream than have a look at rxjs' `first` and `find` operators.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find). But you don't need to use lodash to do it:

```
your_source.shows.filter(param => {param.id === '2-cde'});
```